# hex to string chinese,chinese hex 2 byte ,english hex 1byte?

Tags: java, string, hex, ascii

this is stringToHexAsciiString.

```
//将字符串转成ASCII十六进制的java方法
    public static String stringToHexAsciiString(String value)  
    {  
        StringBuffer sbu = new StringBuffer();  
        char[] chars = value.toCharArray();   
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) 
        {  
            sbu.append(Integer.toHexString(chars[i]));
        }  
        return sbu.toString();  
    }
```

this is asciiToString begin

```
//将ASCII转成字符串的java方法
    public static String asciiToString(String value)
    {
        StringBuffer sbu = new StringBuffer();  
        //System.out.println("value.length()/2 = " + value.length()/2);
        byte[] chars    = new byte[value.length()/2];
        chars           = hexStringToByte(value);
        //System.out.println("chars.length = " + chars.length);
        for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
            //sbu.append((char) Integer.parseInt(chars[i]));
            byte[] change = new byte[1];
            change[0]     = chars[i];
            //System.out.println("change[0] = " + change[0]);
            sbu.append((char) chars[i]);
            //System.out.println("i = " + i + " " + sbu.toString());
        }


        return sbu.toString();
    }  
    public static byte[] hexStringToByte(String hexString){
        if (hexString == null || hexString.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        hexString = hexString.toUpperCase();
        int length = hexString.length() / 2;
        char[] hexChars = hexString.toCharArray();
        byte[] d = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int pos = i * 2;
            d[i] = (byte) (charToByte(hexChars[pos]) << 4 |charToByte(hexChars[pos + 1]));
//          d[i] = (byte) (hexChars[pos] << 4 |hexChars[pos + 1]);
        }
        return d;
    }
    private static byte charToByte(char c) {
        return (byte) "0123456789ABCDEF".indexOf(c);
    }
```

use test english is ok,chinese is bad.

```
String strAscii = Encrypter.stringToHexAsciiString("汉1232").trim();
            String asciiStr = Encrypter.asciiToString("6c4931323332".toUpperCase());
            System.out.println("asciiStr:"+asciiStr);
            System.out.println("strAscii:"+strAscii);
```

asciiToString result is chinese become messy code

```
asciiStr:lI1232
strAscii:6c4931323332
```

need to 汉1232.stringToHexAsciiString result :chinese char is 2 byte,english is 1 byte。how to div chinese hex and english hex。

Comment: Why do you need to convert Unicode character to ASCII?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. I assume you know that Chinese Hanzi require 2-3 bytes in UTF-8, whereas the Roman character set used in written English only requires one byte per letter (corresponds to original ASCII).

Comment: Are you trying to find the byte(s) associated with a particular character (glyph) in a string? (i.e. break the string into groups of bytes where each group of bytes corresponds to one character?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's the problem in your code... or what exactly you want, this is not clear in your question.
But if you just want convert a String to Hex format then you can try the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class StringToAscii
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        try {
            String s = "汉1232";
            System.out.println(s);
            String hexString = new String(Hex.encodeHexString(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            System.out.println(hexString);
            String unicode = new String(Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray()));
            System.out.println(unicode);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output on my laptop is:

```
汉1232
e6b18931323332
汉1232
```

Comment: know this first。it is useful,but this is used to transfer data for encrypt and decrypt。i can't change other project send data '6c4931323332'。only decrypt  '6c4931323332' to 汉1232。or can help me how to use "Hex.decodeHex" decrypt  '6c4931323332' to 汉1232。your "汉" 's hex is e6b189,my  "汉" 's hex 6c49

Comment: 。 we use your solution for hexString to decrypt and encrypt。thanks for help。There's a problem in old code。chinese and english have different byte.